# Why to use multiple catch blocks?

Tags: try-catch

We can use multiple catch block in Try-Catch.
But my Question is : **why to use multiple catch blocks when it can be done by using single catch block?**

1. Suppose I want exact cause of my problem, I can get that by Ex.message
2. If I want to show customized message to user, I can show it by putting If-Else loop on Ex.Message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **handle the individual exception accordingly.**

For example:
If your program is **handling both database and files**.  If an **`SQLException`** occurs, you have to handle it database manner like closing the dbConnection/reader etc.,  whereas if a **File handling exception** then you may handle it differently like file closing, fileNotFound etc.

That is the main reason in my point of view.

For point numbers 1 and 2:

If showing error message is you main idea then you can use `if..else`.  In case **if you want to handle the exception** then check the above point of my answer.  The reason why I stretch the word **handling** is because it is entirely different from showing a simple error message.

To add some quotes I prefer [**Best Practices for Handling Exceptions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) which says

> A well-designed set of error handling code blocks can make a program
>   more robust and less prone to crashing because the application handles
>   such errors.

Answer (score 1):

This works only if all exceptions share the same base class, then you could do it this way.

But if you do need exception type specific handling, then I would prefer multiple try-catch blocks instead of one with type-depending if-else ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask why do we need the Switch - Case. You can do it with If - Else.

And why do you need Else at all. You can do it with If (If not the first condition, and...).

It's a matter of writing a clean and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

By using single catch clock you can catch `Exception` type - this practice is strongly discouraged by Microsoft programming guidelines. FxCop has the rule `DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes` which is treated as `CriticalError`:

Catching general exception types can hide run-time problems from the library user, and can complicate debugging.

http://code.praqma.net/docs/fxcop/Rules/Design/DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes.html

The program should catch only expected exception types (one ore more), leaving unexpected types unhandled. To do this, we need possibility to have multiple catch blocks. See also:

Why does FxCop warn against catch(Exception)?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx